# What's the best way to explain to a non-CS person why CS concepts are important to their lives?

Tags: math, coding-style, computer-science

Is there a legitimate reason why the majority of society (beyond CS-educated persons) should know about the abstractions we become familiar with in CS/programming (such as data abstractions, computer systems abstractions, etc)? Or does it truly not really matter to anyone but programmers, scientists, and engineers?

Comment: This would be much easier to answer should you provide some examples.

Comment: Are you confused about what I mean by CS concepts? Well, I mean things like Computer System Principles(memory hierarchy, networks, etc), Algorithms, Data Structures, etc. Pretty much anything you may think is important lol

Comment: This question would have been perfect for the upcoming [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science-non-programming?referrer=pdx8p7tVWqozXN85c5ibxQ2). So, if you like to have a place for questions like this one, please go ahead and help this proposal to take off!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason why the majority of society should know about CS concepts. This is not the way society works, IMO. To be honest, a much stronger case could be made why the majority of the people should know about first aid then about CS.

There are a lot of professions out there which are crucial to maintain the standard of living we have now. Computer science is one of them, I'll give you that, so are doctors, engineers, mechanics, teachers,...

The majority of the people already know how to use computers because it's useful to them. Just like you know how to live in your house, you probably don't know how to build one from the ground up.

Comment: Thanks, Nocturn. This was insightful lol

Comment: But don't the abstractions(whether it be data abstractions, computer systems abstractions, etc) you learn in CS give you revolutionizing insight into how things in general work?

Comment: Sure, it can give you an insight and people how want to learn should be given every opportunity to do so. Your question was about the majority of the population. There are beside CS other fields which can give insights to people. What makes CS different than say, math, physics, engineering, linguistics, music theory.. All these fields can offer a different perspective or insight when used in other fields.

Comment: So, there is nothing special about CS?

Comment: CS is special, vital and unique. To a point that all other branches are special. We, as a species, managed to survive because the one you're communicating with doesn't need to understand. To put it simply bear vs man: man loses. Bear vs a coordinated attack: bear loses. Your argument should be that alternative viewpoints should be taken into consideration, even if they can't understand everything behind what led to your conclusion.

Comment: Hmmm... but computers are used everywhere.. you can't deny, right? Not to mention, the importance of computational thinking in our lives?

Comment: I give up.. You win... Is that what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure what youre saying?

Comment: @Jacob Hayden: I'm saying it's ok to be different.

Comment: I don't see a need to become defensive, though